# Wordpress and Rails on same domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, dns

I have an Amazon AWS and I want to install both Wordpress and Rails on this same server using Apache. I know that we can do this by configuring Apache virtual host. The problem is with the domain. Currently, we are using `example.com` for the Wordpress website, this website contains other pages such as blog, help, faq, etc. For the rails app, I want to use the `app.example.com` as the root path. And when an user signs up, I also want to give him a unique subdomain such as `user1.example.com`, `user2.example.com`, etc

How can I achieve such things? I am thinking about using some rewrites to redirect .example.com to Rails app but I don't really know how.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The way the internet works is that you address specific machine by its address - the domain is simply a mechanism to make that address prettier - and by the service port

Now, lets say that you are addressing http://example.com
What do you need the http for? this is the protocol you are using and each protocol had a predefined well known port number

You can address a different port by stating it - example.com:3000 for example

Now, a port is like the access point to some web application, but no two applications on same machine can make use of the same port

This is the reason that you can not run both WordPress and Rails server on the same machine and port

So change the port number, right? Not exactly - Because people will not know on which port you put it and will not be able to access it - However, I'm not sure, but in your Name Service Provider (GoDaddy, Networks Solution etc.) in the CNAME definition you might be able to point http://example.com to [your machine name]:[your port] - I'm not sure , you should check it out

Your options:

1. Use same machine - Leave the WordPress as is, put the Rails on HTTPS (port 8080) - Which is the secured protocol and it is also reasonable if the user need to put in some details that you want to be safe - Then your address will be https://app.example.com and you should update it also in your Service Name Provider settings and also set up a certificate and all read more about it before you start doing that
2. Use two machines - If you use a micro machine for the rails application it costs you nothing and put your DB also on AWS so you will have access to it from both machines

Hope I was helpfull